# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind Glassfish Server

Tags: eclipse-neon

I am using Eclipse Neon version 4.6.0 and Glassfish(Payaraa)4 , when I first installed it, it worked fine but from some days it is not working and I am trying to do this alot but it just don't work. It gives the below error:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
```

I have checked no other server is running in my computer yet I have installed the Apache Tomcat Server. SO I need to know what should I do ?

I have delete and recreate the server, re-install the glassfish tools in eclipse. Even tried to create the domain directory as it also gives the below error:

```
payara-4.1.1.171.0.1\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\bundles does not exist, please create it.
```

Nothing seem to work. I am thinking to switch better to another server but before that I want to know the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

`BindException` means that the given port number is being used by some another server on the computer and to run my server it require to release this port used by another service. So I check through command prompt that, is port 8080 is being used by another service in the system using the below command:

```
netstat -a -o | find "8080"
```

and it showed me the IP and PID that it had used in the system and then from task manager ->Processes I stopped the service and that's how it worked.